# Model's find() method that always modify search criteria

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have `find()` method declared in one of my models (`Lab`) to modify `WHERE` clause in SQL:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['deleted' => false]);
}
```

It modifies search results only when `find()` is called directly. Like that:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Lab::find(),
]);
```

or like that:

```
$labs = Lab::find()->all();
```

But, when any call to this method uses own `where()`, `orWhere()` or `andWhere()`:

```
$labs = Lab::find()
    ->where(Lab::getWhereArray())
    ->orderBy('position')
    ->all();
```

then inner modification is ignored.

This is according to [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecordinterface.html#find()-detail) and it is understandable by me. But, how can force my model to always return modified results. So, no matter, how it is called, it will always modify search criteria?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work if you use andWhere() in the second case?

Comment: Of course, that it will work, when I use `andWhere()` in second case. But, this requires modification of method call in controller or wherever that method is called. And thus, that is not the topic of this question. I'm looking for a solution, that will be 100% based on model itself -- i.e. no matter how someone is going to call my `find()` method, it will _always_ alter search parameters. As it should in given case of "deleted" records. I'm considering, if `afterFind` wouldn't be a solution for me in this case?

Comment: what about using `andWhere` in the overriding `find()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I've tested it at my side. Adding `andWhere()` in `find()`-overriding should do the job.

Just try:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->andWhere(['deleted' => false]);
}
```

Comment: What if they use orwhere? I think this approach will broke

Comment: In the given example normal "where()" is used, what means this criteria should be always used. To make it work "andWhere()" should be used. If "orWhere()" would be used in the second query, "andWhere()" will still be used in the first one.